# expose elasticsearch service directly to the client or put it behind a middleware

Tags: deployment, architecture, elasticsearch, web-deployment

I write a client server application. I have setup an elastic-search service on the server. 
The client(iOS app) queries information from the elastic-search service.
I have two options:

```
1. put the elastic-search behind a nginx server(as proxy server). 
2. write an app running on the middle-ware to wrap the elastic-search APIs(only 
   certain APIs that will be queried by the client).
```

For option 1, all the elastic-search API will be exposed to the client, and to the public at the same-time.

What option should I take? Or there are any other good practice to handle this case?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you should never offer ES-API to the public.
By this, everybody could just delete your indexes change your mappings and do whatever they would want to do... This is just plain dangerous.

Furthermore, the mightyness of this API might be too complex for some clients, that just want to perform some basic operations.
Altough I don't know your requirements, I would recommend you to wrap ES into your own REST-API, that covers the specific needs of the client.

Answer (score 3):

If your client application would make use majority or the whole Elasticsearch API, it makes sense to put it behind a proxy such as Nginx.

If the client application would work with Elasticsearch in a traditional sense (searching, even updating docs), I'd prefer to put a "smarter" proxy in front of it, ie. what you call a middleware, written in Ruby, Python, etc. You have tighter control on the workflow here, though the Nginx proxy act really smart as well.

The more important question is whether you're OK with exposing the Elasticsearch API to the client with something like HTTP Auth or token based authentication. In this way, the credentials are clearly visible to the client, can be intercepted, etc.

There's an example of a OAuth based authentication for Elasticsearch and JavaScript client-side applications in this article: [*JavaScript Web Applications and Elasticsearch*](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/javascript-web-applications-and-elasticsearch/). It uses the *Twitter @Anywhere* (superseded by *Sign in with Twitter*) to authenticate the user without allowing him to bypass the proxy by intercepting the credentials.